# Disable perfomance measures for some transactions in Sentry

Tags: python, django, sentry

Our application written on stack Django\Postgres\Redis\Celery + Vue. As one of the monitoring tool we are using Sentry. Sentry measures performance for transactions. It's possible to control how many transaction will be covered by Sentry with [set up sample rate](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/django/performance/). Also we can control which transaction could be covered with [filtering them by (for example) path](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/django/configuration/filtering/?#using-platformidentifier-namebefore-send-transaction-). How can i exclude transactions from performance monitoring (but still watch them for issues)?